# What is the difference between append and write methods of java.io.writer?

Tags: java, writer

The [java.io.Writer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) interface has two methods called append and write. What are the differences between these two? It even says that

> An invocation of this method of the form `out.append(c)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `out.write(c)`

so what is the reason for having two method name variants?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are minor differences between append() and write(). All of which you can work out by reading the Javadocs. Hint. ;)

- write will only take a String which must not be null and returns `void`
- append will take any CharSequence which can be null and return the Writer so it can be chained.

write is an older style format created before CharSequence was available.

These methods are overloaded so that there is a

- `write(int)` where the `int` is cast to a char. `append(char)` must be a char type.
- `write(char[] chars)` takes an array of char, there is no equivalent append().

Comment: Does that mean that I should use append rather than write? Why couldn't they just have called the overloads with CharSequence write as well and made the old write methods return the writer too?

Comment: @Svish,  That would break backward compatibility.  When code is compiled, the return type is part of the byte code signature and you wouldn't be able to use the new method without re-compiling the code from source. Also you may replace `write(int)` with `write(char)` in Java (which some code changes) but you definitive need to re-compile it.  I would suggest you use `append` if you have no preference.  The reason it has this name is to be consistent with StringBuffer which always used append. StringBuilder/StringBuffer/Writer all share the Appendable interface now.

Answer (score 7):

Probably to conform to the Appendable interface: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html

Answer (score 6):

`Append()` can take a `CharSequence`, whereas `write()` takes a `String`.

Since `String` is an implementation of `CharSequence`, you can also pass a `String` to `append()`.  But you can also pass a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` to `append`, which you can't do with `write()`.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from the documentation, append also returns the Writer you have just written to so that you can perform multiple appends such as:

```
out.append(a).append(b).append(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Writer.append(c)` returns the Writer instance. Thus you can chain multiple calls to append, e.g. `out.append("Hello").append("World")`;

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's a byproduct of the `Appendable` interface which `java.io.Writer` implements in order to provide compatibility with `java.util.Formatter`.  As you noted, the documentation points out that for `java.io.Writer` there is no practical difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

What has been noted above is true. The different flavours of `BufferWiter`'s `append()` method return a `Writer`, which implements `Appendable`, among others, thereby affording you the ability to chain calls. In addition, `append()` allows you to pass a `CharSequence` as well as a `char`, as opposed to an `int`, `String` or `char[]`, as with the `write()` methods. All correct.

However, as the question states, an important issue to point out that the underlying behaviour of `append()` is still much the same as that of `write()`. Despite the somewhat misleading nomenclature, existing file content will be overwritten, **not appended**, unless your `FileWriter` is instantiated otherwise:

```
try (var writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myFile.txt", true));) {
    writer.append("XXX").append("ZZZ");
}
```

In that sense I think the original question raises a valid point.