# Before creating the file , deleting the file of previous day

Tags: java, file

I am creating a dat file in C: drive folder named abc as shown below , Now my file is generated everyday
now suppose if my file is generated today, then tommrow it will be also generated as usual
but when tommrow it is generated I have to make sure that earlier day file is deleted as the space in that folder is limited and this check is every time need to be done previos day file to be get deleted from that folder , please advise how to achieve this..

```
File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName()); //filepath is being passes through //ioc         //and filename through a method 


        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(
                file);

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fileOutput));
```

Comment: Just dont check that file exists or not. Write the content with same file name. It automatically replace the previous file. and if file doesn't exist then it will create one.

Answer (score 7):

why not use `file.delete()` ?

```
File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName()); //filepath is being passes through //ioc         //and filename through a method 

if (file.exists()) {
     file.delete(); //you might want to check if delete was successfull
}
file.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutput));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file name same in time to time no need to delete that. By running your code tomorrow, will over write file created today.

Consider following case

```
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\Test\test.txt"));
    bw.write("abbbb");
    bw.close();  // now this will create a test.txt in side Test folder
```

now run this by change writing String

```
    BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\test.txt"));
    bw.write("hihi");
    bw.close(); // now you can see file only containing hihi
```

Comment: Can you add some references?

Comment: I was actually hoping for some documentation abt write overwriting. Am trying to find something about "write" and "append" modes, but no luc

Comment: `apend()` will add new content to already existing file. we can call it as update. But if we use `write()`, that will create new file.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, what I am asking is if you have any proof, javadocs links n such.. much of what I am looking at is saying that write and append are equivalent..

Comment: @KarthikT take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949926/what-is-the-difference-between-append-and-write-methods-of-java-io-writer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35975/discussion-between-ruchira-and-karthik-t)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code this way:

```
 if (file.exists()) {
      file.delete();
 }
 file.createNewFile();
```

And if it does not work, it's a matter of permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using Java 7 then there is standard way to get file creation time, So that you can check if file is created in previous day and should be delete.

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/filepath/");
    BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println("creationTime:"+ fileAttributes.creationTime());
```