# Unable to append to file based on file.length() operation

Tags: java, file

I want to append to the file and if its not empty; and want to write if its empty. Below is is my code. write function works, append is not. Can anyone guide here?

```
public class Filecreate {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("newFileCreated.txt");
    System.out.println("file path "+file.getAbsolutePath() +" file length - "+file.length());
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    if((int)file.length() != 0){
        myWriter.append("appended text\n");
    }else{
        myWriter.write("Files in Java might be tricky, but it is fun enough!");
    }
    myWriter.close();
    System.out.println("file length after writing to file "+file.length());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about whether or not the file contains anything. Just apply the argument of **true** to the ***append*** parameter in the [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) constructor then always use the **Writer#append()** method, for example:

```
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
String file = "MyFile.txt";

FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(file, true)
myWriter.append("appended text" + ls);

/* Immediately write the stream to file. Only really 
   required if the writes are in a loop of some kind 
   and you want to see the write results right away. 
   The close() method also flushes the stream to file 
   before the close takes place.  */
myWriter.flush();   

System.out.println("File length after writing to file " + 
                   new File(file).length());
myWriter .close();
```

- If the file doesn't already exist it will be automatically created
  and the line appended to it.
- If the file is created but is empty then the line is appended to it.
- If the file does contain content then the line is merely appended to
  that content.

Comment: it's working with true argument. But both append and write works the same way. Is there not difference between append and write when we use true for filewriter?

Comment: **Peter Lawrey** explains it quite well in [this SO Answer Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949975/4725875).

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs because you measure file's size after you open it. Thus, you have to check file's size before you open it. Also, I won't recommend to cast long to int, because your solution won't work on big files. To conclude, following code will work for you:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("newFileCreated.txt");
    long fileSize = file.length();
    System.out.println("file path "+file.getAbsolutePath() +" file length - "+file.length());
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(file);

    if(fileSize > 0L){
        myWriter.append("appended text\n");
    }else{
        myWriter.write("Files in Java might be tricky, but it is fun enough!");
    }
    myWriter.close();
    System.out.println("file length after writing to file "+file.length());
}
```